# How does collections.namedtuple work?

Tags: python, namedtuple

I am studying  the code of "namedtuple" in Python.(Python 3.6.3). I run the code :

```
from collections import namedtuple,_iskeyword
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'],rename=False,verbose=True)
p = Point(2,3)
print(p)
```

and then the console print such as :

```
from builtins import property as _property, tuple as _tuple
from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter
from collections import OrderedDict

class Point(tuple):
    'Point(x, y)'

    __slots__ = ()

    _fields = ('x', 'y')

    def __new__(_cls, x, y):
        'Create new instance of Point(x, y)'
        return _tuple.__new__(_cls, (x, y))

    @classmethod
    def _make(cls, iterable, new=tuple.__new__, len=len):
        'Make a new Point object from a sequence or iterable'
        result = new(cls, iterable)
        if len(result) != 2:
            raise TypeError('Expected 2 arguments, got %d' % len(result))
        return result

    def _replace(_self, **kwds):
        'Return a new Point object replacing specified fields with new values'
        result = _self._make(map(kwds.pop, ('x', 'y'), _self))
        if kwds:
            raise ValueError('Got unexpected field names: %r' % list(kwds))
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        'Return a nicely formatted representation string'
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '(x=%r, y=%r)' % self

    def _asdict(self):
        'Return a new OrderedDict which maps field names to their values.'
        return OrderedDict(zip(self._fields, self))

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        'Return self as a plain tuple.  Used by copy and pickle.'
        return tuple(self)

    x = _property(_itemgetter(0), doc='Alias for field number 0')

    y = _property(_itemgetter(1), doc='Alias for field number 1')
```

this is the class definition, I am confused with the class's definition:

```
x = _property(_itemgetter(0), doc='Alias for field number 0')
```

At here the property as `_property`, the `fget` function of property  is `_itemgetter(0)`.

My question is:

***What the return of `_itemgetter(0)`?***

***How does the `_property` work in this case?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

It allows you to use `p[0]` as well as  `p.x` to retrieve the value `2`:

```
>>> p.x
2
>>> p[0]
2
```

## Explanation

`property` allows you to call a method without the `()`.
So `p.x` instead of `p.x()`.

`itemgetter(0)` is a function for the `[]` indexing syntax.
In this case it gets the element at this index from the underlying tuple.

It returns a new function:

```
>>> f = _itemgetter(0)
```

Calling this function:

```
>>> f(t)
10
```

has the same effect as:

```
>>> t[0]
10
```

Finally, `property` makes it "callable" without adding the `()`at the end.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: In the code x = _property(_itemgetter(0),...) , it do not pass a instance  to _itemgetter, you mean it pass instance of type underlying

Comment: With `p.x` you call `p._itemgetter(0)()`, i.e. the bound method. This is equivalent to `_itemgetter(0)(p)`.